# cannot install @material-ui/core using npm

Tags: npm, material-ui

I tried to install @material-ui/core librabry but then npm throws the error below

I used the

`npm install @material-ui`

command

````
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: school-demo@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from @material-ui/core@4.11.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/freduah/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/freduah/.npm/_logs/2020-11-02T14_50_03_045Z-debug.log
freduah@freduah:~/school-demo$ ```
````

Comment: Please refer to https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v4.11.2

Answer (score 8):

I had come across the same problem. These worked for me:

1. For core: `npm -f install @material-ui/core`
2. For icons: `npm -f install @material-ui/icons`

Comment: But this comes with security vulnerabilities, so if you are working on a production application try to fix them first, for side projects this is okay.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to install it by force by adding '-f':

```
npm install -f @material-ui/core
```

Answer (score 3):

MaterialUI 4 doesn't support React 17 yet. Please check the issue created on github https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/23306.

Answer (score 2):

you can downgrade your react, it worked for me by this command:(I downgrade from v17)

```
npm install --save react@16.13.0 react-dom@16.13.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Material UI is using emotion as a styling engine by default. If you want to use styled-components instead, run:

try to use this
npm install @mui/material @mui/styled-engine-sc styled-components

i highly recommend to read the document in thar website and not from npm

Answer (score 1):

**This worked for me**

`npm install -force @material-ui/core`

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

worked for me. Which I found on https://mui.com/

Answer (score 0):

check your react versian, MaterialUI 4 doesn't support React 17. you can change youre version by

1. npm install --save react@16.13.0 react-dom@16.13.0
   make sure Assuming you're using npm/yarn or another node package manager, dependency versions are listed in package.json.
   Search for the react and react-dom packages under dependencies (or devDependencies) and replace their versions with 16.13.0. Then run npm install or yarn or whatever package manager you're using. This should be enough to downgrade to React 16.

Answer (score 0):

Try
yarn add @material-ui/core & yarn add @material-ui/core
React 17 dont support material UI install previous versions or use yarn It will take some time but work perfectly fine

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** npm install @material-ui/core

**Solution:**
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

**OR**
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Answer (score 0):

npm install -f @material-ui/core

or

npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps

or You can downgrade react

npm install --save react@16.13.0 react-dom@16.13.0

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
npm install @material-ui/core --force
```